# Return to the function loop when user didn't input anything in scanf() in C

Tags: c, string

main() won't loop when input from scanf() is empty (nothing happened when I hit "Enter" key after the "prompt" printed out in the shell. It's a truncated version of what I was trying to build. Very new to C, could really need some help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int main(){

    char string1;
    printf("prompt");
    scanf("%s", string1);
    if(!string1){
        return main();
    }
    printf(" %s", string1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `char` is not a string.

Comment: would it work if I use char string[10] instead?

Comment: You should always check the function `scanf` return value too. Anyway `string1` is *uninitialised* so testing its value is useless if `scanf` fails.

Comment: @Z.Winter It would at least scan it. Anyway, I'm not entirely sure what are you trying to do with `if (!string1)`. Actually, I have no idea what you're trying to do with `if (!string1)`.

Comment: "would it work if I use char string[10] instead" it might but you could be a victim of a buffer overflow exploit. Are you following a tutorial course or guessing?

Comment: @MarkWeston  The if statement was supposed to be testing if string1 is NULL of not; not sure if it's the legitimate way of doing it.

Comment: @Weather Vane  I guess a little bit both, being following tutorial and online searching non-stop for the project.